# Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I just got the info that my jQuery function is not working on IE nor Edge. In the console I have the message:

**Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'**

This is the jQuery:

```
$('body').on('change', 'select', function (event) {
    if(event.target.id.indexOf("couche") >= 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ redir2 }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ident: event.target.id,
                value: event.target.value,
                iscouche: "True"
            },
        }).done(function (msg) {
            if(msg.nothing == 1) {
                var what = event.target.closest('tbody');
                $(what).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
            } else {
                var add = event.target.closest('tr');
                var toremove = msg.toremove.split(" ");
                for(var i = 0; i < toremove.length; i++) {
                    if(toremove[i].length > 0) {
                        jQuery(toremove[i]).remove();
                    }
                }
                jQuery(add).after(msg.ret);
            }
        });

    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ redir2 }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ident: event.target.id,
                value: event.target.value,
                iscouche: "False"
            },
        }).done(function (msg) {});
    }
});
```

Can someone tell me if there's a fix for that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`event.target` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object so has no jQuery methods

In jQuery instead use `$(this)` which is a jQuery object.

I also suggest you don't use the target if you do not need to.

**UPDATE:** the newer browsers now has the DOM method [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), so OPs code would work in newer browsers except IE.

Here is a fixed jQuery version:

```js
$('body').on('change', 'select', function(event) {
  var $sel = $(this),    // the changed select
    id = this.id,        // or $(this).attr("id"); 
    val = $(this).val(); // or this.value
  if (id.indexOf("couche") >= 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ redir2 }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        ident: id,
        value: val,
        iscouche: "True"
      },
    }).done(function(msg) {
      if (msg.nothing == 1) {
        var what = $sel.closest('tbody')
        $(what).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      } else {
        var add = $sel.closest('tr');
        var toremove = msg.toremove.split(" ")
        for (var i = 0; i < toremove.length; i++) {
          if (toremove[i].length > 0) {
            jQuery(toremove[i]).remove();
          }
        }
        jQuery(add).after(msg.ret);
      }
    });

  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ redir2 }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        ident: id,
        value: val;,
        iscouche: "False"
      },
    }).done(function(msg) {});
  }
});
```

or neater:

```js
$('body').on('change', 'select', function(event) {
  var $sel = $(this), // the select changed
    val = this.value,
    id = this.id,
    isCouche = id.indexOf("couche") != -1;
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ redir2 }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      ident: id,
      value: val,
      iscouche: isCouche ? "True" : "False";
    },
  }).done(function(msg) {
    if (isCouche) {
      if (msg.nothing == 1) {
        var what = $sel.closest('tbody')
        $(what).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      } else {
        var add = $sel.closest('tr');
        var toremove = msg.toremove.split(" ")
        for (var i = 0; i < toremove.length; i++) {
          if (toremove[i].length > 0) {
            $(toremove[i]).remove();
          }
        }
        $(add).after(msg.ret);
      }
    } else {
      // handle not couche
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 17):

[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is defined on jQuery prototype, it cannot be used on plain JavaScript object.

`event.target` is the DOM element on which the event has occurred, to use jQuery methods on it, the element need to be wrapped in the jQuery.

Change

```
var what = event.target.closest('tbody')
```

to

```
var what = $(event.target).closest('tbody')
```

Comment: Why use event.target at all?

Comment: @mplungjan Right, but as you've answered use of `$(this)`, I'll not add that in answer. :). Using `this` is correct way.

Comment: may need to update to something like this if using it as a conditional: if($(event.target).closest('tbody').length > 0)

Answer (score 3):

Yuo must inclose it in `$()` as `event.target` is not a jQuery element

```
   $(event.target).closest('tr')
```